# Merge tags "tab" and "tabs"

Tags: support, tag-synonyms

Both [tab](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/tab) and [tabs](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/tabs) refer to the exact same thing and thus should be merged.

Comment: This issue isn't that easy to solve. One common meaning, if you've looked at the questions, is *tab character* ASCII `0x09`, the other is the *tab* user interface element.

Comment: [This question](http://superuser.com/questions/362270/last-tabs-in-user-data-how-do-i-open-it-into-tabs-on-chrome) refers to the _tab_ GUI element. And so does [this](http://superuser.com/questions/368571/can-each-firefox-tab-have-its-own-keyboard-layout-language). Thus, for the ASCII character, in my opinion, the tag should be _character-tab_, or something similar.

Comment: Some of the question even use it for the *Tab* key, which is different thing. As I said, it's just not that easy as ignoring the problem and merging two tags.

Comment: I think, if we act on these tags, we should do it right. Clear up the ambiguity, so the tags we provide will actually have real meaning. Right now, they don't. Not really.

Comment: @DanielBeck I agree.

Answer (score 6):

There are three different uses I can think of:

- Tab key
- Tab character
- Tab UI element

While the Tab key usually generates the tab character, they should still be treated separately. If you're asking how to make the tab key insert a tab character, you're probably doing something wrong or need to read a `vi` tutorial.

---

I suggest we do the following instead of simply merging:

- Search the *tab character* and *tab key* uses of `tab` and `tabs`, and retag them to `tab-key` and `tab-character` (or `tabulator-key`, if that's common in English? I'm not sure whether it helps or detracts...)
- Create a new tag `tabbed-interface` (or `tabbed-ui` / `tab-ui`?) and make both `tab` and `tabs` synonyms.
- Create tag wikis for these tags, clearly describing what each tag is for, maybe (not in the excerpt, but the actual wiki) linking to the other, similar but unrelated tags.

The reasons:

- The 3rd meaning is the most common, i.e. tabbed interface. Therefore this is the target of the synonyms `tab` and `tabs`.
- All tags start with `tab`, so users who type this will be presented all of these as options. `tab` and `tabs` will not be presented, as they're synonyms, so users will get the choice of three distinct options.

Comment: +1, though you have my vote against tabulator-key (quite uncommon to me) and tab-ui (programming term).

Comment: @tom what's your suggestion for the name of the tabbed interface tag?

Comment: tabbed-interface is very layman which is why I would prefer it. Dunno if the term UI is really commonly known by everybody, as it is still an industrial term...

Comment: Makes sense. I also prefer `tabbed-interface`.