# Tab Tab Tab, is this browser on

Tags: discussion, tag-cleanup-request

We currently have multiple tab tags open on our site:

[tabs](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/tabs) Tabs are a graphical user interface feature that allows multiple documents to be contained within a single window.

[browser-tabs](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/browser-tabs)
The  tag has no usage guidance, can you help us create it?

The last possibly from [an earlier cleanup](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/3892/merge-tags-tab-and-tabs).

I suggest moving the remaining browser based tags to browser-tabs or all to tabbed-interface. (which a browser interface is just one specific instance off. So tab-interface would be more generic than browser-tab, worksheet-tab, beer-on-tab, ...)

Comment: Are browser tags any different than everything else tagged as "tabs"? Or are there multiple "tab" categories that are remaining?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I don't see the point in *any* tab-related tag. I'd vote for cleaning them all up and synonymizing them with [useless](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/useless).

The last part is a joke ;P

Comment: Concur. I don't think there's anything in-scope for SuperUser that involves tabs, which is both different from other problems affecting a given product *and* universally-applicable to tab-related problems in all applications.

Comment: So, tabs are not Super. ;-)

Comment: @clacke Tabs are awesome. But telling people that your problem involves tabs is as helpful as telling people that your problem involves buttons. It isn't helpful at all.

Comment: I have a problem that involves **computers**. Can we make a tag for that?

Comment: @DanHenderson I couldn't have said it better myself!  Of course we use tabs every day, but will we ever need a question *about the tabs themselves*?

Comment: Jokes aside, has anyone read the original cleanup @Hennes mentions? http://meta.superuser.com/questions/3892/merge-tags-tab-and-tabs?lq=1 points out there are legitimate questions related to the tab-key and/or the tab-character.

Comment: @OliverSalzburg A quick look at the [tabs](http://superuser.com/questions/tagged/tabs) and [browser-tabs](http://superuser.com/questions/tagged/browser-tabs) tags shows that there are many questions where the tag is more noise than signal, but also several that are actually specifically about the interaction between tabs, tab-specific preferences or plugins etc.